# Redirect output of batch command to an if statement (and string error?)

Tags: batch-file

After a bit of research I've found what looks to be a good work around for getting the output of a batch command and setting it to a variable. I've used a bit of [example code](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/save-output-of-dos-command-to-variable.html) from a blog: Just Geeks to start. My eventual goal is to detect the model of computer the script is run on and do something based on which model. After a bit of modification I have:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic csproduct get name') do ( 
if %%A == "Vostro 430" goto vostro430
if %%A == "Optiplex 380" goto optiplex380
)
exit

:vostro430
REM do some stuff here

:optiplex380
REM do some stuff here
```

Its useful to note that wmic csproduct get name > sometextfile.txt on a Vostro 430 (dell computer model) a text file that looks like this:

```
Name
Vostro 430
```

So the code above "should" ignore the first line and compare "Vostro 430" in the if statements and then jump to one of the lables. It seems that I have some error though if I echo the out the batch script I can see that it is evaluating %A as a blank:

```
== "Vostro 430" goto vostro430
== "Optiplex 380" goto optiplex380
```

Any ideas where I messed up? I suspect some sort of string or syntax issue but I haven't been able to pin it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aphoria pointed you need quotes around the `%%A`.

But the main problem is the output of the wmic command,
as it outputs in unicode format.

Try this code to see the effect

```
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic csproduct get name') do ( 
    echo .............1%%A2
)
```

The output will be something like

```
2............1TravelMate 7720
2............1
```

What happens here? The lines are appended with a `<CR>` character, so the `2` will be print at position 1 of the line.

You can avoid this with simply removing the last character from `%%A`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic csproduct get name') do ( 
    set "line=%%A"
    set "line=!line:~0,-1!"
    echo "!line!"
)
```

Or you use the `TYPE` command to normalize the output

```
wmic csproduct get name > wmicOutput.tmp
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('type wmicOutput.tmp') do ( 
    echo Works too "%%A"
    if "%%A"== "Vostro 430" goto :Vostro
)
```

Comment: Thanks, your first recommendation worked well, with a slight modification: set "line=!line:~0,-3!" apparently there are a couple of extra characters after each line.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes around `%%A`...like this:

```
if "%%A" == "Vostro 430" goto vostro430
if "%%A" == "Optiplex 380" goto optiplex380
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to get a whole line in `for /F` command is via tokens=* or delims=", but not both. Use only delims this way:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic csproduct get name') do ( ...
```

Also, you must add quotes in `%%A` value for the correct comparison in the `if` command, as aphoria said.

Comment: You can use both, it's even a bit faster than using only `delims=`. Using `tokens=*` without delims isn't recommended, as leading spaces would be removed